# How to manually set a color of a LineSeries via json config in amcharts v4?

Tags: json, colors, line, amcharts, amcharts4

How to manually set a color of a LineSeries via json config in amcharts v4?

I've tried lots of properties and it had no effect:

```
    ...
    "series": [
        {
            "type": "LineSeries",
            "propertyFields": {
                "stroke": "#color",
                "fill":   "#color"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "LineSeries",
            "color": "#color"
        },
        {
            "type": "LineSeries",
            "fill": "#color"
        },
        {
            "type": "LineSeries",
            "sprite": {
                "color": "#color"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "LineSeries",
            "sprite": {
                "fill": "#color"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "LineSeries",
            "stroke": {
                "color": "#color"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "LineSeries",
            "stroke": {
                "fill": "#color"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Does amcharts v4 have a simple and easy way to manually set a color of a line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. You have to set the `stroke` at the top-level of the LineSeries definition ([see JSON tab in the docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/series/#Simple_properties)):

```
"series": [{
  "type": "LineSeries",
  "stroke": "#567890",
  // ...
},
// ...
]
```

JSON values line up very closely to the declarative syntax, hierarchy-wise. You can find more full JSON examples in the [github repo](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/tree/master/dist/script/examples/json).